# unable to sort or print out array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I got a task to write the methods to 1. take information in and save it into array, 2. to copy the array(only with previously given arguments) and 3. to sort the array to be in descending order. it seems to me like i got the first 2 parts working but i have been stuck on the third method for 2 days without any progress. i am still learning java so i'm pretty sure i have made a dumb mistake somewhere. thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.*;
public class RevisionExercise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      
        int[] tempArray = new int[100];
        System.out.println("Type in numbers. Type zero to quit.");
        int amountOfNumbers = askInfo(tempArray);
       
        int[] realArray = new int[amountOfNumbers];
        copyInfo(realArray, tempArray);
      
        setArray(realArray);
        
        printArray(realArray);
    }
    public static int askInfo(int[] tempArray) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print((i+1) + ". number: ");
            tempArray[i] = reader.nextInt();
            if (tempArray[i] == 0) {
                return tempArray[i];    
            }
        }
        return i;
    }   
    
    private static int[] copyInfo(int[] realArray, int[] tempArray)
    {
        int targetIndex = 0;
        for( int sourceIndex = 0;  sourceIndex < tempArray.length;  sourceIndex++ )
        {
            if( tempArray[sourceIndex] != 0 )
                tempArray[targetIndex++] = tempArray[sourceIndex];
        }
        realArray = new int[targetIndex];
        System.arraycopy( tempArray, 0, realArray, 0, targetIndex );
        return realArray;
    }
    
    public static int[] setArray(int[] realArray)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <realArray.length; i++) {     
          for (int j = i+1; j <realArray.length; j++) {     
              if(realArray[i] >realArray[j]) {
                 temp = realArray[i];    
                 realArray[i] = realArray[j];    
                 realArray[j] = temp;    
               }     
            }
        }  
        return realArray;
    }   

    public static void printArray(int[] realArray ) {
        System.out.println("\nOrdered array: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < realArray .length; i++) {
            System.out.println(realArray [i]);
        }
    }
}
```

the output i'm getting looks like this.

```
Type in numbers. Type zero to quit.
1. number: 3
2. number: 8
3. number: 5
4. number: 6
5. number: 9
6. number: 0

Ordered array:
```

while it should look like this:

```
Type in numbers. Type zero to quit.
1. number: 3
2. number: 8
3. number: 5
4. number: 6
5. number: 9
6. number: 0

Ordered array: 
9
8
6
5
3
```

Comment: change this line. realArray= setArray(realArray);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in calculating the total numbers entered by the user. Your function always return 0. So change it to something like this:

```
public static int askInfo(int[] tempArray) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int totalNumbers = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print((i+1) + ". number: ");
        int number = reader.nextInt();
        if (number != 0) {
            totalNumbers++;
            tempArray[i] = number;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return totalNumbers;
}
```

Chage the sort function to this:

```
public static void setArray(int[] realArray) {
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < realArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < realArray.length; j++) {
            // Use < for descending order and > for ascending order
            if(realArray[i] < realArray[j]) {
                 temp = realArray[i];
                 realArray[i] = realArray[j];
                 realArray[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your main program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] tempArray = new int[100];
    System.out.println("Type in numbers. Type zero to quit.");
    int amountOfNumbers = askInfo(tempArray);

    int[] realArray = new int[amountOfNumbers];
    copyInfo(tempArray, realArray, amountOfNumbers);    

    setArray(realArray);

    printArray(realArray);
}

public static int askInfo(int[] tempArray) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int totalNumbers = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print((i+1) + ". number: ");
        int number = reader.nextInt();
        if (number != 0) {
            totalNumbers++;
            tempArray[i] = number;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return totalNumbers;
}

private static void copyInfo(int[] tempArray, int[] realArray, int size) {
    for( int sourceIndex = 0;  sourceIndex < size;  sourceIndex++ )
    {
        realArray[sourceIndex] = tempArray[sourceIndex];
    }
}

public static void setArray(int[] realArray) {
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < realArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < realArray.length; j++) {
            if(realArray[i] < realArray[j]) {
                temp = realArray[i];
                realArray[i] = realArray[j];
                realArray[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void printArray(int[] realArray ) {
    System.out.println("\nOrdered array: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < realArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(realArray [i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the notice, after i changed it i am getting a following error:
`
Ordered array: 
0
0
0
0
0
`

Comment: @Arzidal I posted the complete code, see if you made a mistake somewhere

Comment: on my end everything except setArray methods work, i did test each method by printing their return values but setArray is giving me only zeroes. at this point im not really sure what might cause the issue

Comment: @Arzidal you didn't forgot this call, System.arraycopy(tempArray, 0, realArray, 0, amountOfNumbers);

Comment: correct, i did forget the call. when testing in VS it works perfectly, now i need to find a way to add it somewhere besides main method since the platform im learning on has disalbed main method editing for the code

Comment: @Arzidal I update the answer to include a function to how to copy the arrays

Comment: @Arzidal can you tell me why you  changed the accepted answer ??

Comment: my mistake, fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

General remark: Each of your methods returns an array but you never use this return value.

There are 2 modifications necessary to fix your code:

1. Keep the value of the method output:

   `realArray=copyInfo(realArray, tempArray);`

   So you put the result of the copy in the `realArray` variable.
2. You expect the askInfo method to return the number of entered numbers but in fact you return the value of the last entered number.

   So instead of `return tempArray[i];` you have to `return i;`

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, in the `askInfo` method, the size of the `realArray` will always be 0, since `amountOfNumbers` is the return of

```
if (tempArray[i] == 0) {
        return tempArray[i];
}
```

because your condition is `tempArray[i] == 0`, hence you are always returning 0. Then your `copyInfo` method is returning an array but you have nothing receiving the returned array. I would suggest changing your `copyInfo` method to

```
private static int[] copyInfo(int[] tempArray)
{
    // same
    int [] realArray = new int[targetIndex];
    // same 
}
```

and your `main` method to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //same
    int[] realArray = new int[amountOfNumbers];
    realArray = copyInfo(tempArray);
    // same
}
```